# How to use nodejs debug module but only for some directory?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I have my app started with:

```
NODE_ENV=development DEBUG=* node-supervisor server
```

but that will debug everything (everything from node_modules)

How can I exclude node_modules from debug or how can i debug only one directory?

I am using: https://github.com/visionmedia/debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't debug one directory, but you *can* make sure that only your own code's debug messages are shown:

```
// your code
var debug = require('debug')('my-code');
debug('hello world');

// to only show debug messages from your own code:
DEBUG=my-code node-supervisor server
```

You can even create a subdivision to debug only parts of your code:

```
// file1.js
var debug = require('debug')('my-code:file1');

// file2.js
var debug = require('debug')('my-code:file2');
```

If you only want to see debug messages from `file1.js`:

```
DEBUG=my-code:file1 ...
```

Or show all debug messages from your code by using a wildcard:

```
DEBUG=my-code:* ...
```

Comment: thank you. this is great. Do you know where can i find docs on operators %s - string, %o  - object and so on?

Comment: @pregmatch I think that it uses [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format) under the hood, so look there for supported placeholders.